# How to Add a file Successfully to BTsync folder in Phone?

Tags: bittorrent-sync

This is a bug occurred in earlier <2.3.3 and now in 2.3.5. It was resolved for 2.3.4 but occurs now again. 
The problem occurs in phones: Android, iPhones. Android 6.0 tested and CyanogenMod 13.

Do

- Create "a folder" in your phone's BTsync.
- Add a file there in the folder and you see "You added 1 file in BTSync".
- You see the file unstably in the folder. Mostly, no file seen in 2.3.5.

I really hope that the bug fix could be implemented in the main stream and not only in the subtrees as was done with 2.3.4. 
I forwarded this thread to the developers such that we have a history what is occurring.

---

How can you add a file successfully to BTSync folder in Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am right. I got an official email about the case and a new bug fix as an attachment

> Sorry, but the fix was not delivered to 2.3.5 (beta).

The fix will be in the coming releases.